# How to send a Document ID link instead of a general link

Tags: hyperlink, document-id

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I would like to set up my site so that when users send links to documents, they send the permanent URL related to the Document ID, instead of the standard link that is broken every time a document is renamed or moved.

Right now, I've got the Document ID service configured, and my items all have IDs assigned.  However, when I click on the drop-down menu for a document and choose Send to - then Email a Link, the link that is sent is NOT the permanent one related to the Document ID.  This makes having document IDs sort of useless, since end users are going to pick the most obvious way to send and store links, not manually grab them from each document's properties list.  Is there a way to change this so that the document link is the permanent one?

Thank you!

Comment: Cannot verify it right now, but I belive that you might be able to do this with some ad-hoc custom actions. That would meand develop a solution - don't know if you want to go that extra mile.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but you could create a workflow that replicates the send link function and configure it to send the document ID link instead.

Answer (score 0):

A search query link for that Doc ID seems to be the easiest solution (provided the Doc Id is indexed of course).